# compare counts of matches

Tags: graph

I have a dataset of people who like shops. and shops located in regions. The people also live in the regions.

I need to find the users who Don't like all of the shops located in the SAME region in which they live.

If i get the count of shops the user likes in their region, and get the amount of shops in a region, and if the counts aren't the same, am I right in thinking this should work?

Comment: You want to find people who don't like any shop in the region in which they live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that will help here is the `all()` predicate.

Here's how to find the people who like every shop in the region where they live.

```
MATCH (shop:Shop)-[:SITUATED]->(region:Region)
WITH region, collect(shop) as shops
MATCH (person:People)-[:LIVES]->(region)
WHERE ALL(shop in shops WHERE (person)-[:LIKES]->(shop))
RETURN person
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to find people who don't like any shop in the region in which they live. If that's what you want then try

```
MATCH (people:People)-[:LIVES]->(region:Region)
WHERE NOT (people)-[:LIKES]->(:Shop)-[:SITUATED]->(region)
RETURN people
```